# Добавление message в repeated поле на python

Tags: python, google-protobuf

У меня есть `repeated command sendCommand = 1` в моем proto файле. Я заполняю command в цикле (command является message, в свою очередь). Как мне сделать так, чтобы command на каждой итерации цикла добавлялось в sendCommand?
Возможно я не совсем понимаю как работает protobuf, так как я в нем новичок.
Код такой:

```
ar_post = request.POST
sendCommand = my_proto_pb2.sendCommand()
for i in range(len(ar_post.getlist('param1'))):
    command = sendCommand.command()
    command.param1 = ar_post.getlist('param1')[i]
    command.param2 = ar_post.getlist('param2')[i]
    command.param3 = ar_post.getlist('param3')[i]
    sendCommand.append(command)
print(sendCommand.SerializeToString().hex())
```

Метод append() не работает, но суть того, что я хочу он отражает.

Comment: Без кода не очень понятно, что происходит. Добавьте код прямо в вопрос.

Comment: @CrazyElf, добавил код по вашим рекомендациям.

Comment: Это хорошо. Я не спец по `protobuf`, но может кто ответит. С кодом всегда лучше, понятнее вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел в чем была проблема, я должен был добавлять сообщения так `sendCommand.sendCommand.append(command)`. Я просто обращался к элементу более высокого уровня, а не к самому repeated полю.